# PageSpeed Insights, WebP and <picture> element

Tags: image, pagespeed, webp

I recently launched a new website, vanillagorillahosting.com. It scores 100/100 on PSI but PSI gives me the suggestion to use next-gen image formats. And I would love to! My very optimized banner is about 200k in jpg but about 75k in webp. However, Safari doesn’t support webp. It is starting to support webp with the new Safari 14 (Sept 2020) BUT it seems that’s only if it’s Safari 14 used on the new OS/iOS, Big Sur. Since Big Sur does not support my iMac (and I believe adoption will be too low for the time being) I can’t rely on Safari’s webp support.

So, I turn to CSS and the CSS picture element. Great, a jpg banner for Safari and a webp banner for everyone else. Awesome, it works! Except suddenly my PSI score drops and my Cumulative Layout Shift goes way up.

I really want to use webp images but can’t have a big white box appear for Safari users. And I don’t want to compromise my PSI score. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this issue? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Care to share your HTML? It is very hard to diagnose without some markup / code to look at.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I believe this was the css I used:

Comment: <picture>
  <source type="image/webp" srcset=“i/website-hosting-banner.webp"> 
  <img src=“i/website-hosting-banner.jpg" width="1920" height="962" alt="Vanilla Gorilla Website and Email Hosting Calgary Alberta">
</picture> It works, but it's too much of a compromise to use. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without messing up how the page loads?

Comment: looks fine, at this stage maybe fallback to feature sniffing for WebP and then swap the source. The downside of this is that you need to have the `src` blank when the page loads and then put the correct `src` once you have sniffed for WebP compatibility. You may also want to have a `<noscript><img></noscript>` fallback. This will get the performance figures you want (make sure you have a defined height and width for the image container or you may get high Cumulative Layout Shift) but obviously it is harder to maintain.

Comment: Awesome, Graham, I will try it!